# SQL Update take long time with First_Value function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table KYCCUST and FINACLE_TEMP_in_kyc1. They are in different databases then I want to do some update.

```
UPDATE  KYCFBHK.KYCFBHK.KYCCUST
SET KYC_SP_08=
(SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(KYC_SP_08) over (partition by CUSTNO order by DATE desc) FROM AMLETL.dbo.FINACLE_TEMP_in_kyc1 t1 

WHERE CUSTNO collate Latin1_General_BIN2 = KUNDNR AND HISTBIS ='9999')

WHERE HISTBIS = '9999'
```

The sub query "Select First_value" return result in 10 secs but when I do the update. It took 1hours and still not yet finish. Can we reduce time run?
Our DBMS is MSSQL Server 2016. And in these tables, we also have index.

Comment: Why don't you break down the query to find out what is going wrong. I suggest to run `SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(KYC_SP_08) over (partition by CUSTNO order by DATE desc) FROM AMLETL.dbo.FINACLE_TEMP_in_kyc1 t1 
WHERE CUSTNO collate Latin1_General_BIN2 = KUNDNR` and check the execution plan or estimated execution plan. It may give you an indication what is consuming the time. Also a good exercise I usaully do is SELECT INTO a new table FROM AMLETL.dbo.FINACLE_TEMP_in_kyc1 and try the above query on that table (without indexes etc...), use DTA on that query to find missing indexes etc...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi. Our purpose is to update a column in a table with correct data while previous time, the value is not correct. Btw We've changed to Update and using Inner join stead. Then it took only 50s to update all

Answer (score 0):

It worked with query below:

```
update T1
SET T1.KYC_SP_08=T2.Kyc_sp_08 
from KYCFBHK.KYCFBHK.KYCCUST T1 
Inner join AMLETL.dbo.FINACLE_TEMP_in_kyc1 T2
ON T2.CUSTNO  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 = T1.KUNDNR
And T1.HISTBIS=9999
And T2.Date in (select max(date) from AMLETL.dbo.FINACLE_TEMP_in_kyc1)
```